Объект слишком сильно опускается
Немного программирую в Roblox Studio на языке Lua, и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть 2 скрипта: 1 скрипт поднимает объект на 1000 единиц по координате Y вверх. А второй должен его возвращать, т.е. отнимать от позиции объекта (1000 по Y) ещё 1000, и должно получиться так, что объект вернулся в первоначальную позицию. 1-ый скрипт, который поднимает, работает стабильно. А который опускает - нет. Когда объект опускается, он уходит под пол и его координаты по Y -975. Помогите пожалуйста найти в чём ошибка! Вот 2 скрипта
1-ый скрипт:
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService") 
local object = workspace.Entry
local FL = object.jaderni_uskorL.Cylinder
local FR = object.jaderni_uskorR.Cylinder
local ZL = object.jaderni_uskorZL.Cylinder
local ZR = object.jaderni_uskorZR.Cylinder
local WallB = object.Union
local WallL = object.WallL
local WallR = object.WallR
local Krysh = object.Krysh
local Floor = object.Floor
local Chair = object.PlasticChair.Seat
local Chair1 = object.PlasticChair1.Seat
local ChairL = object.PlasticChair
local ChairR = object.PlasticChair1


local endOffset = Vector3.new(0, 1000, 0)

local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    12,               
    Enum.EasingStyle.Quad,    
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
    0,               
    false,          
    0                
)

local tweenPosition = TweenService:Create(object, tweenInfo, {Position = object.Position + endOffset})

local FRTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(FR, tweenInfo, {Position = FR.Position + endOffset})

local FLTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(FL, tweenInfo, {Position = FL.Position + endOffset})

local ZRTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(ZR, tweenInfo, {Position = ZR.Position + endOffset})

local ZLTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(ZL, tweenInfo, {Position = ZL.Position + endOffset})

local WallLTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(WallL, tweenInfo, {Position = WallL.Position + endOffset})

local WallRTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(WallR, tweenInfo, {Position = WallR.Position + endOffset})

local FloorTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(Floor, tweenInfo, {Position = Floor.Position + endOffset})

local KryshTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(Krysh, tweenInfo, {Position = Krysh.Position + endOffset})

local WallBTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(WallB, tweenInfo, {Position = WallB.Position + endOffset})

local ChairTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(Chair, tweenInfo, {Position = Chair.Position + endOffset})

local Chair1TweenPosition = TweenService:Create(Chair1, tweenInfo, {Position = Chair1.Position + endOffset})

local Chair2TweenPosition = TweenService:Create(ChairL, tweenInfo, {Position = ChairL.Position + endOffset})

local Chair3TweenPosition = TweenService:Create(ChairR, tweenInfo, {Position = ChairR.Position + endOffset})



script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function() 
    script.Parent:Destroy()
    object.Attachment.ProximityPrompt:Destroy()
    tweenPosition:Play()
    FRTweenPosition:Play()
    ZRTweenPosition:Play()
    FLTweenPosition:Play()
    ZLTweenPosition:Play()
    ChairTweenPosition:Play()
    Chair1TweenPosition:Play()
    Chair2TweenPosition:Play()
    Chair3TweenPosition:Play()
    WallBTweenPosition:Play()
    WallRTweenPosition:Play()
    WallLTweenPosition:Play()
    FloorTweenPosition:Play()
    KryshTweenPosition:Play()
end)

2-ой скрипт:
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService") 
local object = workspace.Entry
local FL = object.jaderni_uskorL.Cylinder
local FR = object.jaderni_uskorR.Cylinder
local ZL = object.jaderni_uskorZL.Cylinder
local ZR = object.jaderni_uskorZR.Cylinder
local WallB = object.Union
local WallL = object.WallL
local WallR = object.WallR
local Krysh = object.Krysh
local Floor = object.Floor
local Chair = object.PlasticChair.Seat
local Chair1 = object.PlasticChair1.Seat
local ChairL = object.PlasticChair
local ChairR = object.PlasticChair1

local endOffset = Vector3.new(0, -1000, 0)

local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    12,               
    Enum.EasingStyle.Quad,    
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
    0,               
    false,          
    0                
)

local tweenPosition = TweenService:Create(object, tweenInfo, {Position = object.Position + endOffset})

local FRTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(FR, tweenInfo, {Position = FR.Position + endOffset})

local FLTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(FL, tweenInfo, {Position = FL.Position + endOffset})

local ZRTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(ZR, tweenInfo, {Position = ZR.Position + endOffset})

local ZLTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(ZL, tweenInfo, {Position = ZL.Position + endOffset})

local WallLTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(WallL, tweenInfo, {Position = WallL.Position + endOffset})

local WallRTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(WallR, tweenInfo, {Position = WallR.Position + endOffset})

local FloorTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(Floor, tweenInfo, {Position = Floor.Position + endOffset})

local KryshTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(Krysh, tweenInfo, {Position = Krysh.Position + endOffset})

local WallBTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(WallB, tweenInfo, {Position = WallB.Position + endOffset})

local ChairTweenPosition = TweenService:Create(Chair, tweenInfo, {Position = Chair.Position + endOffset})

local Chair1TweenPosition = TweenService:Create(Chair1, tweenInfo, {Position = Chair1.Position + endOffset})

local Chair2TweenPosition = TweenService:Create(ChairL, tweenInfo, {Position = ChairL.Position + endOffset})

local Chair3TweenPosition = TweenService:Create(ChairR, tweenInfo, {Position = ChairR.Position + endOffset})





script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function() 
    script.Parent:Destroy()
    tweenPosition:Play()
    FRTweenPosition:Play()
    ZRTweenPosition:Play()
    FLTweenPosition:Play()
    ZLTweenPosition:Play()
    ChairTweenPosition:Play()
    Chair1TweenPosition:Play()
    Chair2TweenPosition:Play()
    Chair3TweenPosition:Play()
    WallBTweenPosition:Play()
    WallRTweenPosition:Play()
    WallLTweenPosition:Play()
    FloorTweenPosition:Play()
    KryshTweenPosition:Play()
end)


Подскажите, а принципиально возвращать с помощью -1000? Может быть стоит вернуть на прошлую позицию с которой был старт?

Здравствуйте! Спасибо огромное! Да, стоило просто указать позицию с которой начинался старт! Не знаю, как это работает, вроде по логике должны отниматься координаты)) Ещё раз спасибо!!!
